# How to put contents of multidimensional array into a neatly formatted string?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, multidimensional-array, printf

I'm looking for a quick and easy way to take the contents of a multidimensional array and convert to a nicely formatted string.  The string would (preferably) be the same as what we get when we:

```
echo "<pre>" . print_r($_POST) . "</pre>";
```

I could reproduce that with a home-grown function, but am hoping there is a built-in function to handle this (one I haven't so far been able to locate on php.net).

Thanks for any tips/pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do `$str = print_r($_POST, true);`

Comment: Perfect, I thought I remembered seeing this in the documentation but I skipped right over it a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 3):

[print_r()](http://www.php.net/print_r) accepts a second parameter that when == true returns the output as a string instead of sending to the buffer.